# How to replace a string by a subtring in postgres?

Tags: postgresql, replace, sql-update, substring

I have the following file name in a column on my db: /folder/path/24/24_1543250974365.wav

And I want to replace it by: 24_1543250974365.wav

In summary, I need to cut off the path and replace it by what comes after the last "/" in the String.

My idea is to find the last occurrence of "/" and get the string from there to the end and do a replacement, but not sure if that's the best way to do that

```
UPDATE tablename
SET file = REPLACE(file, file, substring('/', 1))
WHERE id=1;
```

I'll need a function that replace all data in this column, so I don't have anymore the entire path but only the file name. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You might have to add or subtract 1, but this should work

```
 right(file,strpos(reverse(file),'/'))
```

Comment: thanks man, that's really it, I just neded to subtract 1 as you said. This 'reverse' is a nice solution

Answer (score 0):

select right(file,position('/' in reverse(file))-1)